# JavaScript Function to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been getting interested in Angular recently and I was trying it out but having a little bit of a difficulty.

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function toggle(target) {
            var curVal = document.getElementById(target).style.visibility;
            document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = (curVal === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        };
```

It changes the value between `visible` and `hidden`on each click of the following button:

```
<button class="btn-info" onclick="toggle('theBox')" type="button">Toggle Box</button>
```

I am trying to do this same thing in Angular, just not sure how, as far as I understand Angular is the same as JavaScript in terms of the functions.. I just don't understand how to do this same operation using Angular.

Answer (score 1):

With angular, you don't even need a javascript function for toggle:

Button:

```
<button ng-click="isShown = isShown ? false : true" type="button">Toggle Box</button>
```

"Box":

```
<div ng-show="isShown"></div>
```

Just read about "ng-click" and "ng-show" or "ng-if".

Comment: I am trying this: 

I have my button like this:
`<button ng-click="isShown = isShown ? false : true" type="button">Toggle</button>`

And then I have my display like this:
`<div id="container" class="container">            
   <embed src="www.google.com/pdf1.pdf" width="400" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf">
   <embed ng-show="isShown" src="www.google.com/pdf1.pdf2" width="400" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf2"> 
    </div>`
but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is just a JavaScript library. You can use the same JavaScript you are already using, as long as you include the JavaScript file which has the function on the page you're calling this function from.

Depending on which version of angularJS you're looking at using, you can leverage the library.

In angular 1.x you can use the ng-click directive http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-click.asp

In angular 2 you can use click in the template, have a look at the list of events: http://learnangular2.com/events/

Comment: "You can use the same JavaScript you are already using, as long as you include the JavaScript file which has the function on the page you're calling this function from." is really bad advice.  I mean, yeah, you *can* do that, but it doesn't mean you *should*.   Angular doesn't tend to mix well with non-angular javascript, especially any that wants to modify the DOM.

Comment: I was addressing the posters realization that angular is JavaScript, "as far as I understand Angular is the same as JavaScript in terms of the functions". While gathering some resources to help using actual angular functionality.

Comment: OK, that is not at all clear in your answer -- it looks like you're suggesting just dropping his existing script into an Angular app, which would not work (because Angular wouldn't know about the styling set by this non-angular code, and would overwrite any changes it made on the next `$digest`.)